# Android MVP: Error Handling from Model class / manually trigger error

Tags: android, error-handling, mvp

I have read the [articile](https://trivedihardik.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/how-to-avoid-force-close-error-in-android/) , and the great solution provided is working  perfectly in Activity environment.
I tested it with

```
int a = 1/0;
```

in *onCreate*. And the custom exception handler did triggered.

Currently my app adopted MVP architecture. There are some codes implemeted in Model or Presenter layer like

```
 try {
        data = getStringFromFile(fileLocation);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

which might throw exception. However, the exceptions that caught within Presenter or Model layer is not triggering the default exception handler.

What should I do in order to makes the throwable exception from Model or Presenter layer triggers the custom UncaughtExceptionHandler I had created?

And also, is there anyway to trigger the custom UncaughtExceptionHandler manually by using my self defined exception.

Comment: Throw the exception e from the catch block in Presenter class. Since your presenter class is handled by the Activity class it will throw the exception to your Activity class, where you have already handled Exception.

Comment: Model classes generally have getters and setters only. There should not be any exception.

Comment: @nnn Sorry, my Model is also included those Engine/Service/Manager/Helper classes. I tried to throw Exception from Presenter, however, Android Studio asked me to wrap the presenter with try/catch. May I know what is the proper way to handle it in View classes?
int a = 1/0 never prompt the error message and force me to wrap it with try/catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the code in your presenter in try catch and then throw the exception from catch block to handle it by the parent class:

```
public void getData() throws Exception
try {
        int a = 1/0;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```